# representing order without arrays in sql

Tags: sql

I have the following tabular data, which I need to represent in a relational database (along with lots of other stuff!):

```
customer   valueID_1   valueID_2 response
-----------------------------------------
1          None        None      "hello"
1          1           None      "hi"
1          None        1         "wassup"
1          1           1         "goodbye"
```

`valueID_1` and `valueID_2` both reference the same primary key in another table.

I understand it is bad relational database design to recreate this format in SQL and that I should avoid arrays if possible.  My incomplete solution is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE example 
(
    customer int4    references customers(customer),
    valueID  int4    references values(valueID),
    valueID_position int4
    response varchar

    PRIMARY KEY (customer, valueID, valueID_position, response)
);
```

Which would look like this:

```
customer   valueID   valueID_position response 
----------------------------------------------
1          None      1                "hello"
1          None      1                "wassup"
1          1         1                "hi"
1          1         1                "goodbye"
1          None      2                "hello"
1          None      2                "hi"
1          1         2                "wassup"
1          1         2                "goodbye"
```

I would then create a view to allow me to see the information as previously displayed:

```
CREATE VIEW example_view
   SELECT 
       t1.customer, t1.valueID as valueID_1, t2.valueID as valueID_2, response
   FROM t1 AS (

AS SELECT customer, valueID, response
FROM example
WHERE valueID_position = 1)

LEFT JOIN t2 AS(

SELECT customer, valueID, response
FROM example
WHERE valueID_position = 2)

ON t1.customer = t2.customer
AND t1.response = t2.response
```

1. Does this capture my goal?
2. Is there a better way?!

Comment: Instead of `PRIMARY KEY` on all columns, introduce another unique id column

Comment: Normally for holding arrays of data in SQL, you'd have a separate table for just those values. For example if I have a bunch of Dogs and each has an array of Fish they ate - I'd have a table of Dogs, with a record per dog, then a separate table of ConsumedFish where each record has a foreign key to the Dog that ate it (i.e. Many fish to each Dog). A join will then bring that data together nicely. Perhaps I'm missing what you meant though.

Comment: It is not clear (to me) what you are modeling. For each "Example", do you have zero, one, or two "Values" (where it does not matter if they are a first or a second value), or, for each "Example", do you have zero or one "Value" as the first value, AND zero or one "Value" as the second value?

Comment: For each record the response depends on the valueID's and their position.  The meaning of the table is not that interpretable because this is a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  ID         int      primary key identity(1,1)
  CustomerID int      not null  references customers(customerID),
  Value1ID   int      null      references values(valueID),
  Value2ID   int      null      references values(valueID),
  response   nvarchar not null
);
```

You can `insert` your data into this table and just `select` directly from it; no need for a view.

Comment: Is this not bad practice though? Because when you want to select records that contain a certain valueID you need to search over 2 columns instead of one.

Comment: This is not bad practice - it reflects the actual structure of your data, and is going to be way faster than adding views with joins and so forth to get the values in 1 column. Beware of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) - especially when you're working with an unfamiliar technology.